# Which of the following equations must be true?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$C =\frac{5}{9} (F - 32)$$

The equations above shows how temprature $F$, measured in degrees fahrenheit, relates to a temprature $C$, measured in degrees Celcius. Based on the equation, which of the following must be true?

**I**. A temprature increase of $1$ degree fahrenheit is equivalent to a temrature increase of $\frac{5}{9}$ degrees Celsius.

**II**. A temprature increase of $1$ degree Celsius is equivelent to a temprature increase of $1.8$ degrees Fehrenheit.

**III**. A temperature increase of $\frac{5}{9}$ degree Fahrenheit is equivalent to a temperature increase of $1$ degree Celsius.

A. **I** only.

B. **II** only.

C. **III** only.

D. **I** and **II** only.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Either  A or D .. But not sure yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of the equation as an equation for a line.

*$$y=mx+b$$*

where

*$$C= {5}/{9} (F−32)$$*

or

*$$C={5}/{9}F −{5}/{9}(32)$$*

you can see the slope of the graph is ***${5}/ {9}$***, which means that for an increase of ***1*** degree Fahrenheit, the increase is ***${5}/ {9}$*** of ***1*** degree Celsius. Therefore, statement ***I*** is true.

This is the equivalent to saying that an increase of ***1*** degree Celsius is equal to an increase of ***${9}/ {5}$*** degrees Fahrenheit. Since ***${9} {5}$ = 1.8***, statement ***II*** is true.

On the other hand, statement ***III*** is not true, since a temperature increase of ***${9}/ {5}$*** degrees Fahrenheit, not ***${5}/ {9}$*** degree Fahrenheit, is equal to a temperature increase of ***1*** degree Celsius.

***The final answer is D.***

Comment: Well explained, thanks! :D